# How to operate on a vector with a matrix after changing basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Say I have a linear map $T(x,y,z) = (2x+y,5y+3z,8z)$

and the matrix with of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is

$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$

When I operate with that matrix on the vector $(x,y,z)$, this is the rule I use:

$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$ $(x,y,z) = x \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + y \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 5\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + z \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 3\\ 8 \end{pmatrix}$

Which gives me the desired result of $T(x,y,z) = (2x+y,5y+3z,8z)$

But when I diagonalize the matrix with respect to the eigenvector basis $(1,0,0) , (1,3,0) , (1,6,6)$ , I get the diagonal matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$

Now my question is, how do I use this new diagonalized matrix to operate on $(x,y,z)$ to get $(2x+y,5y+3z,8z)$ ? It's obvious that my rule above won't work and that's due to the change of basis but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: That’s not quite right, since multiplication of a $3\times3$ matrix by a $1\times3$ matrix is undefined. Your $(x,y,z)$ must be a _column_ vector.

Comment: It’s not really clear to me what you’re asking here. You just left-multiply the vector by the matrix as you would otherwise. You have to take care that the bases in which they’re expressed match and be aware that the result is going to be relative to some other basis, too.

Comment: So the basis of the matrix is $(1,0,0) , (1,3,0) , (1,6,6)$
If I change the basis of the column vector to match the basis of the matrix, the vector will be $\begin{pmatrix} x-y+ \frac{z}{6}\\ y- \frac{z}{3}\\ \frac {z}{6} \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: My question is, suppose I was given that diagonal matrix with no other information, and I want to use it to transform the vector $(x,y,z)$, I will not obtain $(2x+y,5y+3z,8z)$, how do I obtain it though?

Comment: Without knowing anything else or making some assumptions, you can’t.

Comment: Okay I got it now, if I multiply $\begin{pmatrix} x-y+ \frac{z}{6}\\ y- \frac{z}{3}\\ \frac {z}{6} \end{pmatrix}$ by $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$ I will get $\begin{pmatrix} 2x-2y+\frac{z}{3}\\ 5y-\frac{5}{3}z\\ \frac {4}{3}z \end{pmatrix}$ which is the same vector as $ (2x+y,5y+3z,8z)$ with respect to $(1,0,0) , (1,3,0),(1,6,6)$